# Boundary and Closure $B = \{\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{5},..\} $

Tags: general-topology

Consider the set $B = \{\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{5},..\}   $

At the moment I am a little bit confused and not sure if my answer is right. So I would argue that this is just a union of single points. Since every point itself is closed and contains only its boundary the boundary of this set is $ \delta B = \{\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{5},...,0\} $ - $0$ is included since this set obviously converges against $0$. Thus, the closure $\overline{B}$ is the equal to the boundary.

Is this reasoning right? I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answers are correct but your arguments lack rigour.

I would argue that the interior of $B$ is empty: if $x \in B$, then any open interval around $x$ contains an irrational number, so it can't be contained in $B$. Hence $\partial B = \overline B \setminus B^{\circ} = \overline B$.

That $\{0\} \cup B \subset \overline B$ is clear since $(1/n)_n$ is a sequence in $B$ converging to $0$. Now in general, in any topological space, if $(x_n)$ is a sequence converging to $x$, then $\{x_n: n \in \Bbb N\} \cup \{x\}$ is *compact*. It follows that $B \cup \{0\}$ is a compact subset of $\Bbb R$, and since the latter is Hausdorff, $B\cup \{0\}$ is closed. Therefore:

$$B \subset B \cup \{0\} \subset \overline B \implies \overline B \subset \overline{B \cup \{0\}} = B \cup \{0\} \subset \overline B$$

i.e. $\overline B = B \cup \{0\}$.